# .NET MVC-4 routing with custom slugs

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm rewriting a website project with ASP.Net MVC 4 and I find it difficult to setup the right routes. The url structure is not RESTful or following a controller/action pattern - the pages have the following structure of slugs. All slugs are saved in the database.

```
/country
/country/carmake
/country/carmake/carmodel
/custom-landing-page-slug
/custom-landing-page-slug/subpage
```

Example:

```
/italy
/italy/ferrari
/italy/ferrari/360
/history-of-ferrari
/history-of-ferrari/enzo
```

Since `Country`, `Car Make` and `Car Model` are different models/entities, I would like to have something like a CountriesController, CarMakesController and CarModelsController where I can handle the differing logic and render the appropriate views from. Furthermore, I have the custom landing pages which can have slugs containing one or more slashes.

My first attempt was to have a catch-all `PagesController` which would look up the slug in the database and call the appropriate controller based on the page type (eg. `CarMakesController`), which would then perform some logics and render the view. However, I never succeed to "call" the other controller and render the appropriate view - and it didn't feel right.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify: I do not want a redirect - I want to delegate the request to a different controller for handling logic and rendering a view, depending on the type of content (`Country`, `CarMake` etc.).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since your links looks similar, you can't separate them at the routing level. But here are good news: you can write custom route handler and forget about typical ASP.NET MVC links' parsing.

First of all, let's append `RouteHandler` to default routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
).RouteHandler = new SlugRouteHandler();
```

This allows you to operate with your URLs in different ways, e.g.:

```
public class SlugRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var url = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.TrimStart('/');

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            PageItem page = RedirectManager.GetPageByFriendlyUrl(url);
            if (page != null)
            {
                FillRequest(page.ControllerName, 
                    page.ActionName ?? "GetStatic", 
                    page.ID.ToString(), 
                    requestContext);
            }
        }

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }

    private static void FillRequest(string controller, string action, string id, RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");
        }

        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controller;
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = action;
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] = id;
    }
}
```

Some explanations are required here.

First of all, your handler should derive `MvcRouteHandler` from `System.Web.Mvc`.

`PageItem` represents my DB-structure, which contains all the necessary information about slug:

[image: PageItem structure]

`ContentID` is a foreign key to contents table.

`GetStatic` is default value for action, it was convenient in my case.

`RedirectManager` is a static class which works with database:

```
public static class RedirectManager
{
    public static PageItem GetPageByFriendlyUrl(string friendlyUrl)
    {
        PageItem page = null;

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(/*YourConnectionString*/);
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from FriendlyUrl where FriendlyUrl = @FriendlyUrl";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FriendlyUrl", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = friendlyUrl.TrimEnd('/');

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    page = new PageItem
                               {
                                   ID = (int) reader["Id"],
                                   ControllerName = (string) reader["ControllerName"],
                                   ActionName = (string) reader["ActionName"],
                                   FriendlyUrl = (string) reader["FriendlyUrl"],
                               };
                }
            }

            return page;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this codebase, you can add all the restrictions, exceptions and strange behaviors.

It worked in my case. Hope this helps in yours.

Comment: Is there a difference between inheriting from MvcRouteHandler and implementing IRouteHandler?

Comment: @autonomatt, that's a good question. I believe there's no big difference, at least in this case, since `Route.RouteHandler` property is `IRouteHandler` and `MvcRouteHandler` is just a basic implementation of it. So if you don't use its other methods, `IRouteHandler` will be even cleaner.